# How to Count number of rows in every column that meets a specific criteria in R

Tags: r

Good Afternoon!

I've looked through stackoverflow, but I can't find my exact question so here we go.

I have the below dataframe:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime   point   sound
  50      80       50
  80      80       20
  5       90       80
  0       10       80
  50      80       50
  80      80       20
  5       90       80
  0       10       80
  5       90       80
  0       10       80
")
```

For each column, I would like to know the percentage of observations that are greater than or equal to 50. I would like the finished product to look like this.

```
mydata2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime   point   sound
  40%     70%     80%
")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be:

```
colSums(mydata >= 50)/nrow(mydata) * 100

 rime point sound 
   40    70    80
```

If you need it as a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(rbind(colSums(mydata >= 50)/nrow(mydata)))
```

Comment: This does get me the answer, BUT I need the end product to be a dataframe :)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `colMeans` and multiply by 100

```
100 * colMeans(mydata >= 50)
#   rime point sound 
#  40    70    80
```

If it needs to be a data.frame

```
as.data.frame.list( 100 * colMeans(mydata >= 50))
#    rime point sound
#1   40    70    80
```