# How to Count number of rows in every column (by group) that meets a specific criteria in R

Tags: r

I have a similar question as the link here ([How to Count number of rows in every column that meets a specific criteria in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562782/how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-every-column-that-meets-a-specific-criteria-in-r/64563731#64563731)), but I can't seem to use the same solution so I'm reaching out again.

I have a dataset

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime   point   sound   school
  50      80       50     es
  80      80       20     es
  5       90       80     es
  0       10       80     ms
  50      80       50     ms
  80      80       20     ms
  5       90       80     hs
  0       10       80     hs
  5       90       80     hs
  0       10       80     hs
")
```

For each column I would like to know the percent of observations >= 50% by school. The end product should be a dataframe that looks like this.

```
mydata_clean <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime      point     sound     school
  66.7%     100%      66.7%     es
  66.7%     66.7%     66.7%     ms
  0%        50%       100%      hs
")
```

This seems like a clear case for `group_by(School)` then summarize, but I'm not getting the information I need.

I've attempted the following code:

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(rime, point, sound), sum)
```

but this only gives me the sum of each column by group, which is not what I am looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. You can reshape data to long using `pivot_longer()` keeping school variable. After that create a variable to check if value reaches the desired condition. Finally, `summarise()` allows computing the expected values which are formated to percents as you want using `paste0()`. Just a reminder that columns are of type character. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
mydata %>% pivot_longer(-school) %>%
  group_by(school,name) %>%
  mutate(Var=ifelse(value>=50,1,0)) %>%
  summarise(Perc=paste0(100*round(mean(Var),3),'%')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Perc)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   school [3]
  school point rime  sound
  <fct>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 es     100%  66.7% 66.7%
2 hs     50%   0%    100% 
3 ms     66.7% 66.7% 66.7%
```

Comment: This worked! I'd like to ask how you learned this. I've been using Tidyverse for a number of years, but could not have come up with this solution. Any books to point me to that you found helpful?

Comment: @Mishalb Hi dear! Always a pleasure helping others. Well about how I learned, most of I know now is based on practicing daily with similar problems. Also if helpful, data are as matrices so if you expand you can work better around them. If you want to learn more go to this site and look for tags `dplyr` and `tidyverse` many questions have been solved and you can understand by replicating them with the data that other people share!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.
It first transforms the columns to be summarised into logical values based on whether or not they are greater than or equal to 50. Then groups by school and computes percentages.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(across(rime:sound, `>=`, 50)) %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarise(across(rime:sound, mean), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(across(rime:sound, scales::percent))
## A tibble: 3 x 4
## Groups:   school [3]
#  school rime  point sound
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 es     67%   100%  67%  
#2 hs     0%    50%   100% 
#3 ms     67%   67%   67%
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to binary from logical without any `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
mydata %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = - school) %>%
    group_by(school, name) %>%
    mutate(Var = +(value >= 50)) %>% 
    summarise(Perc = str_c(100 * round(mean(Var), 3), '%')) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Perc)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   school [3]
#  school point rime  sound
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 es     100%  66.7% 66.7%
#2 hs     50%   0%    100% 
#3 ms     66.7% 66.7% 66.7%
```